# My shopping app wont add up what the user wants to buy and doesnt print the total cost

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making this mini shopping app and cant work out how to get the code to add the prodcut costs together and then produce the total cost on the page. I also cant work out how to add the delivery into the cost att he end. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />


<script>


    function clickHandler() {
        var orderTotal =      parseInt(document.getElementById('shirtSelect').value * document.getElementById('shirtQuantity').value) + (document.getElementById('tieSelect').value * document.getElementById('tieQuantity').value);

        //Shirt Select
        switch (document.getElementById('shirtSelect').value) {
            case 'whiteShirt':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 10;
                break;
            case 'blueShirt':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 10;
                break;
            case 'redShirt':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 10;
                break;
            default:
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 0;
                break;

        }
        switch (document.getElementById('tieSelect').value) {
            case 'blueTie':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 7.50;
                break;
            case 'blackTie':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 7.50;
                break;
            case 'redTie':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 7.50;
            default:
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 0;
                break;
        }


        alert("Your order total is " + orderTotal);

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="shirtSelect">
    <option value="whiteShirt">White Shirt</option>
    <option value="blueShirt">Blue Shirt</option>
    <option value="redShirt">Red Shirt</option>
</select>

<select id="shirtQuantity">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<!-- TIE HERE-->
<br />
<select id="tieSelect">
    <option value="blueTie">Blue Tie</option>
    <option value="blackTie">Black Tie</option>
    <option value="redTie">Red Tie</option>
</select>
<select id="tieQuantity">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="deliverySelect">
    <option value="standard">Standard: FREE</option>
    <option value="express">Express: £3.00</option>
    <option value="nextDay">Next Day: £5.00</option>
</select>

<br />
<select id="customerType">
    <option value="nonreg">Non-registered: No Discount</option>
    <option value="reg">Registered: 10% Discount</option>
    <option value="VIP">VIP: 20% Discount</option>
</select>
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="clickHandler();">Place Order!</button>
```

Comment: You are doing parseInt(...) on 'shirtSelect', something that has no integer value?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try `alert(document.getElementById('shirtSelect').value)`, you will find that it returns the shirt name. It is wrong to use this value to calculate the `orderTotal`, which will be `NaN`.

The following code snippet will be helpful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />


<script>


    function clickHandler() {
      //alert(document.getElementById('shirtSelect').value)
        var orderTotal = 0; 
        var shirtQuantity = document.getElementById('shirtQuantity').value;
        var tieQuantity = document.getElementById('tieQuantity').value;

      //Shirt Select
        switch (document.getElementById('shirtSelect').value) {
            case 'whiteShirt':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 10*shirtQuantity;
                break;
            case 'blueShirt':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 10*shirtQuantity;
                break;
            case 'redShirt':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 10*shirtQuantity;
                break;
            default:
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 0;
                break;

        }
        switch (document.getElementById('tieSelect').value) {
            case 'blueTie':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 7.50*tieQuantity;
                break;
            case 'blackTie':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 7.50*tieQuantity;
                break;
            case 'redTie':
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 7.50*tieQuantity;
            default:
                orderTotal = orderTotal + 0;
                break;
        }


        alert("Your order total is " + orderTotal);

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="shirtSelect">
    <option value="whiteShirt">White Shirt</option>
    <option value="blueShirt">Blue Shirt</option>
    <option value="redShirt">Red Shirt</option>
</select>

<select id="shirtQuantity">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<!-- TIE HERE-->
<br />
<select id="tieSelect">
    <option value="blueTie">Blue Tie</option>
    <option value="blackTie">Black Tie</option>
    <option value="redTie">Red Tie</option>
</select>
<select id="tieQuantity">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="deliverySelect">
    <option value="standard">Standard: FREE</option>
    <option value="express">Express: £3.00</option>
    <option value="nextDay">Next Day: £5.00</option>
</select>

<br />
<select id="customerType">
    <option value="nonreg">Non-registered: No Discount</option>
    <option value="reg">Registered: 10% Discount</option>
    <option value="VIP">VIP: 20% Discount</option>
</select>
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="clickHandler();">Place Order!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (shipping not yet implemented):

```
function clickHandler() {
    var orderTotal = 0;

    //Shirt Select
    switch (document.getElementById('shirtSelect').value) {
        case 'whiteShirt':
        case 'blueShirt':
        case 'redShirt':
            orderTotal += 10 * +document.getElementById('shirtQuantity').value;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    switch (document.getElementById('tieSelect').value) {
        case 'blueTie':
        case 'blackTie':
        case 'redTie':
            orderTotal += 7.50 * +document.getElementById('tieQuantity').value;
        default:
            break;
    }

    alert("Your order total is " + orderTotal);
}
```